# Android ListView row background color

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have looked at numerous SO questions and cannot figure this out. I have managed to use a selector to change the hilighting color of my ListView -but how do I set the normal (non-pressed) background colour?

The below XML doesn't work as is only changes my row item background to black once the item has been pressed. How should I be doing this?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/row_hilight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/row_hilight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a default state which does not have state.

Also you need to remove `android:state_pressed="false"` that is because it has the same functionality with the default state.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/row_hilight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/row_hilight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/black"/> //delete this
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> //add this
</selector>
```

Comment: Really? I thought I'd tried doing this and it did the same as the "delete this" line. I'll give it another try when I get home again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rod. I'm afraid it still does the same thing. My ListView contains rows that are actually white on my Android tablet, yet after I touch the rows, they change to black. If I touch another row, the row goes back to white and the newly touched row changes to black - so it is showing the "selected" state rather than the default row state if you follow.

Comment: I found the problem and I'm going to accept your answer. It wasn't behaving as you described because I actually had 2 selectors.. One I had assigned in my row_item.xml file and another, programmatically, I had assigned using getListView().setSelector().

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more item at the end:

```
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_color"/>
```

From the documentation for [state list drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

Therefore, having an item with no specific criteria will match if none of the others do.

Comment: Thanks but @color/default_color results in an error in the XML. @color/transparent (defined as #00000000 in my colors.xml file) seems to return the row to its previous background colour.

Comment: Ahem, default color was just an example. You were supposed to put your own color in there! :-|

Comment: OK :-) Wasn't sure if default_color meant 'use system default color' or whatever. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom listview with a custom adapter:

[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

this was you can use a view with the background you want in getView